# How to switch to a different authorized account in Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am writing a small python script to automate a workflow in my company. I have been testing the code on by inbox so far, as I did not want to mess up anything in the inbox of the actual account this script will be working on. The rest of the code was written, and after testing, I wanted to switch to the other account. So I logged into the new account, made a new project in the console, generated that projects unique client_secret file, and I then swapped out the old client_secret file with the new one, and also updated the project name to the one linked with the new account. However, upon running the script, I realized that the script was still running with my account linked. Im really not sure what else there is I need to replace, or if I am simply missing something?

Here are the relevant parts of my code for this issue:

```
import...

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    lags = None


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_credentials():
   """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

   If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
   the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

   Returns:
       Credentials, the obtained credential.
   """


   home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
   credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
   if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
       os.makedirs(credential_dir)

   credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                  'gmail-python-quickstart.json')
   store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
   credentials = store.get()
   if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
       flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
       flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
       if flags:
           credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
       else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
           credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
       print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
   return credentials
def GetMessage(service, user_id, msg_id, fmt, flds ,mdh):
  """Get a Message with given ID.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.
  Returns:
    A Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format=fmt,fields=flds ,metadataHeaders=mdh).execute()

    #print ('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])

    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):
  """Get a Message and use it to create a MIME Message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.

  Returns:
    A MIME Message, consisting of data from Message.
  """
  try:
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()

    #print ('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])

    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)

    return mime_msg
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
def ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, user_id, query=''):
  """List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    query: String used to filter messages returned.
    Eg.- 'from:user@some_domain.com' for Messages from a particular sender.

  Returns:
    List of Messages that match the criteria of the query. Note that the
    returned list contains Message IDs, you must use get with the
    appropriate ID to get the details of a Message.
  """
  try:
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                               q=query).execute()
    messages = []
    if 'messages' in response:
      messages.extend(response['messages'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                         pageToken=page_token).execute()
      messages.extend(response['messages'])

    return messages
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print ('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """

  message = MIMEText.MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
def GmailInput():
    '''

    :return:
    '''
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    defaultList= ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, 'me', 'subject: claimed infringement label:unread ')
    currentMSG=[]
    ips=[]
    DraftedMessages=[]
    for msg in defaultList:

        currentMSG=GetMimeMessage(service, 'me', msg['id'])
        strCurrentMessage=str(currentMSG)

       #Extract the IP Address Field using the XML included in DMCA emails
        #get a string value of the current message

        if '<IP_Address>' not in strCurrentMessage:
            pass
                #print("XML TAG DOES NOT EXIST")
        else:
            loc1 = strCurrentMessage.find('<IP_Address>')

        if '</IP_Address>' not in strCurrentMessage:
            pass
                #print("XML TAG DOES NOT EXIST")
        else:
            loc2 = strCurrentMessage.find('</IP_Address>')

        #extract the IP address:
        #get rid of the XML identifier in the beginning of the string:
            LOC1=loc1+12

                 #determine legth of ip field
            length=loc2-LOC1
            ipaddress = strCurrentMessage[LOC1 : LOC1+length]
            ips.append(ipaddress)


    print(ips)
    return ips


def main():

    try:
       import argparse
       flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:

       flags = None

    SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'name'

    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

    GmailInstance=GmailInput()

    InfobloxComments=InfobloxLookup(GmailInstance)
    SEPERATED_COLS=[]

    for eachComment in InfobloxComments:
        DividedComments=SplitComments(eachComment)
        SEPERATED_COLS.append(DividedComments)

    columns=defaultdict(list)
    with open('entities_table.csv', 'rb') as ENTITIES:
        reader=csv.DictReader(ENTITIES)
        for row in reader:
            for (k,v) in row.items():
                columns[k].append(v)

    CEN_ENTITIES=columns['Common Name']
    SEPERATED_ENT=[]
    for eachEntity in CEN_ENTITIES:
        DividedEntities=SplitComments(eachEntity)
        SEPERATED_ENT.append(DividedEntities)
    CallGlobalNocScript()
    MakeJSON(InfobloxComments)

    file='email_list.json'
    input_data=json.loads(open(file).read())
    print(input_data)
    for each in input_data:
        pass
       # GmailOutput(each)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I am not a python programmer.  However the client library should be similar to the other ones.  check credential_path look for a file that could be identifying your user.   it will contain json and have access token and refresh token in it.   delete it it will prompt you for login again.  there should be another way of doing it.

Comment: Delete the tokens or the file itself?

Comment: if you delete the file that was used to store the authentication for your user it will prompt you to login again and you can login as another user.  There should be a way with the library to specify different users there is with every other library I am not very good at reading python I couldn't find it.

Comment: just don't delete the jSon credentials file you downloaded from google developers console :) Rename your token file if you like just to be sure I don't break something on you.